# Windows Command for reading bytes sent/received since network interface is connected

Tags: windows, networking, cmd

I want to grab the bytes send/received of a network interface on the windows command line (Win 7/Win 2008 Server).
I already tried the commands netsh, netcfg, ipconfig and net statistics.
No one of them can give me the required information, that I can already see in the interface status GUI (Activities).

Is ist possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that performance monitor provides those information. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection133121120120

The link is somewhat old but you should be able to use that to obtain what you need based on the article.